# Remove overlaping plot values from graph - Androidplot

Tags: graph, label, androidplot

I would like to be able programmatically remove AndroidPlot graph value labels. I've searched a lot over stack questions but didn't find the answer I was lookking for. On this picture I've circled 
[problematic labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffAXq.png).

Comment: Can you share the code you already have for your graph?

Comment: I'll upload during the day ...

Comment: http://pasted.co/7a9d9c9e
http://pasted.co/6a3ecf72